# Parse date with AEDT and AEST time zone in java

Tags: java, date, timezone

I am trying to parse a string of format

```
Thu Apr 07 11:45:28 AEST 2016
```

into date object. My code looks like following:

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
try{
    Date time = parserSDF.parse("Sat Feb 01 15:00:19 AEDT 2014");
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I am getting a 'parse error'. I cannot change the input format of the date and I also cannot set my timezone to a static value as this code is to be run on andorid device. How can I parse this string into date ?

Comment: Can you use the JSR 310 API as this has improved handling of timezones?

Comment: There is no timezone kind of stuff. Can you please elaborate how can i do that.

Comment: You probably need to specify the locale

Comment: Not working with locale as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework ([JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)), you can do:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("Sat Feb 01 15:00:19 AEDT 2014", dtf);
System.out.println(zdt);
```

…which prints:

> 2014-02-01T15:00:19+11:00[Australia/Sydney]

Though why it picks Sydney instead of Melbourne I am not sure.

Comment: It looks like it picked the last one in this list sorted by timezone name alphabetically:  Australia/Currie, Australia/Hobart, Australia/Melbourne, Australia/Sydney.  Each of these timezones are consistent with the input, and with each other on this particular date.  I'm curious what it would do if you gave it date/time/abbreviation that matched two or more timezones that are *not* consistent with each other.

Comment: For example "Thu Apr 07 11:45:28 BST 2016".  This matches Europe/London 2016-04-07 10:45:28 UTC and Pacific/Bougainville 2016-04-07 00:45:28 UTC.

Comment: @HowardHinnant “I'm curious … if it … matched two or more timezones that are not consistent…” That is why you should **avoid using those 3-4 letter zone abbreviations** in the first place. They are not real time zones, not standardized, and not unique (ex: `IST` is India time and Irish time, etc.). Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the format of `continent/region`. And for the sake of both your success and sanity, avoid those old date-time classes (java.util.Date/.Calendar etc.). Use java.time classes as shown here by Lawrey.

Comment: @BasilBourque:  Thanks, I'm relatively familiar with all that.  My curiosity was about how the software responded to such a request.  I credit this question/answer with helping me design how *my* C++ timezone library will respond: http://howardhinnant.github.io/tz.html#Parsing

Comment: Hehe: "Australia/Currie". I assume that was an auto-corrected "Australia/Canberra" (which is where I live), but Australia/Currie, I like it ;)