# How to include DateTimeFormatter to project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) in my project, but Android Studio can't find `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` package.
I downloaded [Java SE Development Kit 8u92](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and in settings of my project I also set "use jdk8".
What am I missing?

Comment: Why you don't use SimpleDateFormat. It's what I use in Android and it workd fine.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is what I am using in Android and it is not working fine. In particular it is unable to parse the time zone AEST (Australian Eastern Standard Time) which DateTimeFormatter apparently does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473928/parse-date-with-aedt-and-aest-time-zone-in-java

Comment: I believe that when the question was asked, the answer was to use ThreeTenABP, the Android adaptation of the backport of java.time. Today core API desugaring seems a more attractive option. See the linked original question (which is later than this one).

Comment: @adalpari and Slartibartfas:t Please not. That would be a sizeable step backward. `SimpleDateFormat` was a notorious troublemaker of a class. The OP is wise in asking how to use its clearly better replacement, `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android, actually you are ussing *Android SDK*, not JDK directly.
You could use SimpleDateFormat:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

Date myDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ZZZZ");
String date = dateFormat.format(myDate);
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarification. I like that in java 8 I can use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` instead of hardcoding pattern myself

Answer (score 1):

From [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) about this class:

> Since:
>   1.8

`Android SDK` is working over `jvm 1.6`

Related answer:
[Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

Answer (score 0):

**Date time formatter**
**Java**
Date time formatter to convert simple date it's very easy in utils class
just like that please check and used this program.

```
public static String getApiSurveyResponseDateConvertToLocal(String date) {

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
       Date datee = inputFormat.parse(date);
        return outputFormat.format(datee);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly disagree. The `SimpleDateFormat`class that you suggest is a notorious troublemaker of a class and fortunately long outdated. No one should use it. The question also wisely asked about its modern replacement, the `DateTimeFormatter` class of java.time, the modern Java date and time API.