# DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-08-13T07:29:12.000+0000' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetimeoffset, date-parsing

Getting a DateTimeParseExcpetion when trying to convert a String `2019-08-13T07:29:12.000+0000` into an `OffsetDateTime`.
The String comes from SalesForce

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-08-13T07:29:12.000+0000", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()))
```

Comment: May be seen as duplicate of [Convert date into AEST using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412345/convert-date-into-aest-using-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom formatter matching to the specific format provided by Salesforce.  In this case, you could try as shown below

```
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
 OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-08-13T07:29:12.000+0000", formatter);
```

More details about formatter could be found https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html