# Java: local date time with unknow suffix

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, datetime-format

I have a timestamp *2019-09-02T09:42:05+0000* . What does the last part *+0000* mean and how to convert this timestamp to *LocalDateTime* object?

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2019-09-02T09:42:05", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
```

works perfectly. I am unable to find appropriate formatter for *2019-09-02T09:42:05+0000*

Comment: `+0000` is a timezone offset.  I suggest you carefully read the Wikipedia page on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date formats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date into AEST using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412345/convert-date-into-aest-using-java)

Comment: Since your string contains a UTC offset (that’s what +0000 is), `OffsetDateTime` is a better matxh than `LocalDateTime` and the one I recommend you parse into. Subsequent conversion to `LocalDateTime` is possible if you know in which time zone you want your `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Subsequent conversion to `LocalDateTime` is always possible. Do you mean `ZonedDateTime`? @OleV.V.

Comment: @Sweeper I mean you need to assume a time zone (or a UTC offset) for that conversion, and if you assume a different time zone from the intended, you will most likely get an incorrect result.

Comment: Yeah, the timestamp is telling you that it's a UTC (or GMT) time. Parse it as what it says it is. Parsing code like that will also work with timestamps that use other offsets.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME option instead. That time stamp has an offset, so you need to use the right formatter.

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2019-09-02T09:42:05+0000", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
```

Documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME

Comment: Unfortunatelly: *Text '2019-09-02T09:42:05+0000' could not be parsed at index 19*

Answer (score 1):

## Offset-from-UTC

> What does the last part +0000 mean

That part is an abbreviated version of `+00:00`. This is a number of hours and minutes (and seconds optionally). That number is the amount of time the date-time is ahead of UTC (to the east) or behind UTC (to the west). An offset of zero means UTC itself itself.

By the way, an offset of zero happens to be used by the time zone of Iceland.

## `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment

> how to convert this timestamp to LocalDateTime object?

You do not.

**`LocalDateTime` is the wrong class.** Your input string represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline. In contrast, `LocalDateTime`, lacking any concept of offset or zone, cannot represent a moment. This is noted in the class Javadoc.

So when do we use `LocalDateTime` with only its date and time-of-day? For three reasons:

- We are describing a time-of-day day to be applied individually in multiple time zones. Perhaps we want to give a half-day off at each our our factories in Delhi, Düsseldorf, and Detroit. We would end out a memo saying all factories will close at `2020-01-23T12:00:00`. This means noon in each locality, with noon arriving much earlier in Delhi first, then hours later in Düsseldorf, and lastly arriving several hours later in Detroit.
- We are booking appointments. Politicians around the world have shown a surprising propensity for changing the offset of their respective time zone(s). So if that next dental appointment is meant to be at 3 PM on the clock after accounting for any such change, then book an appointment with a `LocalDateTime` and a `ZoneId`, each stored separately. When building a calendar schedule with specific points on the timeline, dynamically instantiate a `ZonedDateTime` by combining the two stored pieces.
- When the time zone or offset is unknown. Frankly, I would consider this case inappropriate. If a zone or offset is intended but undetermined, you have bad data. That would be like storing a price of a product without knowing which currency was intended.

For more info, see this Question, [*What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706).

## `OffsetDateTime`

Instead you should be parsing as an `OffsetDateTime`.

You should be able to directly parse that string, as it complies with the ISO 8601 standard used by default in the *java.time* classes. Unfortunately the `OffsetDateTime` may still have a small bug in not being able to parse by default a value where the optional colon in the offset has been omitted. See this Question, [*Cannot parse String in ISO 8601 format, lacking colon in offset, to Java 8 Date*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43360852/642706).

So we need to specify a formatting pattern: `"uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"`.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( 
    "2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX" )
)
```

---

[image: Table of types of date-time class in modern java.time versus legacy.]