# Construct localized date string from a ISO date time string

Tags: java, android, datetime-format

I have a requirement in which I need to render localised datetime on a text view in an Android layout. The date time is returned in an ISO format from a service call. Here is the response JSON

```
{
   "expiredTime": "2020-01-24T00:59:59.000-05:00",
  . . . Other Keys and Values . . .
}
```

This is to be rendered in an Android app inside a text view. What I want to do is show the localised time on the app. So If the user were to view in the screen in say New York, the expired time would show `2020-01-24T00:59:59.000-05:00` because the time in the payload belongs to the same time zone as NY. Similarly, if I wanted to display in GMT, the time would be shown as `2020-01-24T05:59:59.000-00:00`.

How can I implement this correctly in Android? I have done this as shown below. The returned date is passed to a `SimpleDateFormat` instance to return a string.

```
public static final Date parse(String dateTimeAsString) throws ParseException
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.withLocale(Locale.getDefault()));
            try
            {
                LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);
                if (localDate != null)
                    return Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe)
            {
                // If the format is invalid, then delegate to the other helper function.
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Is my implementation to get the localised date correct? If not, how would I do it correctly?
2. How do I localise the date for Android OS version below Oreo? DateTimeFormatter is only available in Android Oreo and up.

Comment: You are really asking two questions in one: (1) How to parse ISO 8601 format? (2) How to display a date according to the user’s time zone? Each has been asked and answered before, so your search engine is your friend.

Comment: When you say localized, do you mean according to the user’s time zone or culture or both? Should the output for a French user in France be `2020-01-24T06:59:59.000+01:00` or something like `24 janvier 2020`?

Comment: @OleV.V. Basically Showing the date in Long Date format in the local time zone.

Comment: For example, show the date as MM-DD-YY hh:mm:ss Z in US, but show it as DD-MM-YY hh:mm:ss Z in Europe for example.

Comment: I think that you can get some of it from this question: [Convert date into AEST using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412345/convert-date-into-aest-using-java). Only since your UTC offset, `-05:00`, has a colon in it, you don’t need the formatter because your format is the default for `OffsetDateTime`. Parsing with just `OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-01-24T00:59:59.000-05:00")` should work. You may also search fore more helpful questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final ZonedDateTime parse(String dateTimeAsString) {
    try {
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeAsString).atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        return delegateToOtherHelperFunction(dateTimeAsString);
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
    String expiredTime = "2020-01-24T00:59:59.000-05:00";
    System.out.println(parse(expiredTime));
```

Output in my time zone:

> 2020-01-24T06:59:59+01:00[Europe/Copenhagen]

For your questions:

> 1. Is my implementation to get the localised date correct? If not, how would I do it correctly?

No, there are a couple of issues with your implementation. I applaud the use of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, though.

- Returning a `Date` won’t give you the time in any particular time zone. A `Date` hasn’t got a time zone. It’s a point in time only.
- A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day, so when using this class you are losing the time part.
- Unimportant, `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` is the same in all locales, so applying a locale to it makes no difference.

> 2. How do I localise the date for Android OS version below Oreo? DateTimeFormatter is only available in Android Oreo and up.

Use the backport. java.time has been backported from Java 8 to Java 6 and 7 and the backport further adapted to early Android API levels. See the links below. If you are writing an app to be supported on several OS versions, I suggest that you simply use the backport throughout (the backport works on high API levels too). I wrote the code above for the backport, so it will work. (I expect it to work on the built-in classes too, not tested).

A note on usage: in computing *localized* usually means adapted to users’ language (and partially their culture), their so-called *locale*, rather than to their time zone. Locale and time zone are orthogonal concepts.

### Links

- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Internationalization and localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) on Wikipedia
- [Localization 101: A Beginner’s Guide to Software Localization](https://www.transifex.com/blog/2015/software-localization-guide/)