# How to convert this string "Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1990" into "1990101"?

Tags: java, regex, string, date, parsing

I have a string "Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1990" and I need to convert it into the format "yyyyMMdd" so in this case it would be "19900101".

I think it's possible to do this with Regular Expressions so that I could pull out the year, month(but would need to convert Jan to 01 and etc) and day from the string but I am not well versed in Regular Expressions. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try using `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: That will not work as he is using a custom date format.

Comment: @Matthew I have given a code sample which outputs `DAY : 19900101`

Comment: I see, didn't know it works with custom formats, good work!

Comment: @Matthew I beg to differ, sorry, getting `SimpleDateFormat` to work is a challenge sometimes, but advising it as a solution is poor advice. That class is notoriously troublesome and fortunately long outdated. We should never use it anymore.

Comment: @Ole V.V I was not recommending its usage or advising it as a solution, I was just explaining that I didn't know that was possible because I don't have enough knowledge about it and then proceeded to say *"good work"* to signal that his solution was better then mine, that's it.

Comment: John-Michael, your string, `Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1990`, very much looks like a string returned from `Date.toString`. So I have added an original question and also provided [a new answer for your here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56374732/5772882) (the new answer doesn’t cover formatting into `19900101`, but that has been covered in the answer by Basil Bourque and is also covered in the first original question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

[Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is overkill.

Here is a one-liner solution using *java.time* classes built into Java.

```
ZonedDateTime                            // Represent a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone).
.parse(                                  // Parse the input text.
    "Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1990" ,     
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( 
        "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" ,   // Specify a custom formatting pattern to match our input.
        Locale.US                        // Specify a `Locale` for the human language to use in translating the name of month& day-of-week.
    )                                    // Returns a `DateTimeFormatter` object.
)                                        // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toLocalDate()                           // Extract the date, without time-of-day and without time zone. 
.format(                                 // Generate text to represent the value of our `LocalDate` object.
    DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE     // Use the predefined formatting pattern YYYYMMDD.
)                                        // Returns a String.
```

> 19900101

## *java.time*

Regex is overkill for this.

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

Specify a custom formatting pattern to fit your input.

Specify a locale to facilitate translating the name of day-of-week and name of month.

### `ZonedDateTime`

Parse as a `ZonedDateTime`, a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a specific region (a time zone).

```
String input = "Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1990";
Locale locale = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , locale );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );

System.out.println( "zdt: " + zdt );
```

> zdt: 1990-01-01T00:00+11:00[Australia/Sydney]

By the way, your input string is in a *terrible* format. It uses the 2-4 character pseudo-zones that are not actual time zones, not standardized, and are not unique! Another problem is depending on English. And it is difficult to parse. Educate the people publishing your data about the beauty of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, created for exchanging date-time values as text.

### `LocalDate`

You want only the date. So extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;  // Extract only the date, leaving behind the time-of-day and the time zone.
```

Your desired output format has already been defined in the `DateTimeFormatter` class. The standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for a date is YYYY-MM-DD. A variation of that is known as "Basic" meaning it minimizes the use of delimiters: YYYYMMDD.

```
String output = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```

> 19900101

Comment: Great answer... it's putting mine too shame, but at least I got some practice out of it. Gonna bookmark it as it will come in handy in the future, thank you.

Comment: @Matthew It good to have a working regex example here as well.

Comment: Does your solution work for any custom date format? If not can you give me an example of a scenario where a regex would be a better solution? I would like to make an implementation for scenarios where using `java.time` is not feasible to make my answer not completely useless :D

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for this informative answer. Yes, the input string is in a terrible format but that is how the ERP system we are using outputs it as.

Comment: @Matthew For multiple formats, you can go either of two ways. You can define a collection of `DateTimeFormatter` objects, each with a custom formatting pattern for one of your expected formats. Then for each input you loop the collection, trying each formatter. If an exception is thrown, you try the next. Alternatively, you can build a more flexible formatter by using the helper class, `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` which can set some optional parts and some default parts. Search Stack Overflow to learn more as this has been addressed many times already. Look esp. for builder examples by Ole V.V.

Comment: @John-Michael I suggest you file an issue ticket with the vendor of your ERP system. Once educated about ISO 8601, it might be trivial (maybe 1 line of code) for them to provide an ISO 8601 compliant string as an alternative to their current output. The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 standard formats by default when parsing/generating text, so you simply call `parse` or `toString` without any `DateTimeFormatter`. See comment by Ole V.V. on your Question for link for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Check if something like this helps

```
//date string
String soTime = "Mon Jan 04 12:30:23 AEDT 1990";

//Format
SimpleDateFormat so = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

SimpleDateFormat desiredFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
desiredFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));

Date sodate = so.parse(soTime);
System.out.println("DAY : " + desiredFormat.format(sodate));
```

[Parse date with AEDT and AEST time zone in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473928/parse-date-with-aedt-and-aest-time-zone-in-java)

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on these classes with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). So should you.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Point noted Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Now assuming that each month and day names inside each passed string is matching one of enum `name` values (i.e *"Mar"* matches the value of field `name` in `Month.MARCH`, while *"Marc"* or *"March"* do not) and the format of the sample string you gave us is truly consistent, as in it is no subject to change during runtime and will always remain `<day-name> <month> <day> <time> <zone> <year>` where year is always a 4 digit number, the following code should answer give you exactly what you want:

**Main Class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String time = "Mon Jul 05 00:00:00 AEDT 1990";
    int result = CustomDateFormat.parseToInt(time);
    System.out.println("Parsed in format [yyyyMMdd]: " + result);
}
```

**CustomDateFormat Class**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CustomDateFormat {

    private static final Pattern STANDARD_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("^(?:[a-zA-Z]{3})\\s([a-zA-Z]{3})\\s([0-9]{2}).*([0-9]{4})");

    /*
     * This is just in case you want
     * the name of the day as well
     */
    public enum Day {

        MONDAY("Mon", "Monday"),
        TUESDAY("Tue", "Tuesday"),
        WEDNESDAY("Wed", "Wednesday"),
        THURSDAY("Thu", "Thursday"),
        FRIDAY("Fri", "Friday"),
        SATURDAY("Sat", "Saturday"),
        SUNDAY("Sun", "Sunday");

        final String shortName;
        final String fullName;

        Day(String name1, String name2) {
            this.shortName = name1;
            this.fullName = name2;
        }

        public static String getFullName(String alias) {
            for (Day d : Day.values()) {
                if (d.shortName.equals(alias))
                    return d.fullName;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }

    public enum Month {

        JANUARY("Jan", 1), FEBRUARY("Feb", 2),
        MARCH("Mar", 3), APRIL("Apr", 4),
        MAY("May", 5), JUNE("Jun", 6),
        JULY("Jul", 7), AUGUST("Aug", 8),
        SEPTEMBER("Sep", 9), OCTOBER("Oct", 10),
        NOVEMBER("Nov", 11), DECEMBER("Dec", 12);

        final String name;
        final int value;

        Month(String name, int value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public static int getMonth(String month) {
            for (Month m : Month.values()) {
                if (m.name.equals(month))
                    return m.value;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static int parseToInt(String date) {

        System.out.println("Parsing date: " + date);
        Matcher matcher = STANDARD_PATTERN.matcher(date);

        if (matcher.find() && matcher.groupCount() == 3)
        {
            int month = Month.getMonth(matcher.group(1));
            int day = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
            int year = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(3));

            if (day == 0 || month == 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to parse day or month from date " + date);
            }
            else return Integer.valueOf(year + "0" + month + "0" + day);
        }
        else throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to parse date " + date);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Parsing date: Mon Jul 05 00:00:00 AEDT 1990
Parsed in format [yyyyMMdd]: 19900705
```

Let me know if this meets your requirements and if any other conditions need to be met or *special case* scenarios considered. It's a fairly simple implementation so it should take no time to adjust it to more specific needs.

**EDIT:** Fix some implementation mistakes, change sample string to a custom one and remove redundant output line.